# RestSharp dll in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2010, nuget, sharepoint-2013, restsharp

I am trying to make Rest Call through C#, to do that I am using RestSharp dll.

I have created farm level solution and added webpart, then installed RestSharp through NuGet.

The issue I am facing is in following line:

`var client2 = new RestClient(webURL);`

The moment I add this line, I am getting 'does not have strong name' error.

```
Referenced assembly 'RestSharp, Version=105.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have a strong name.
```

Then I created a console application added same dll and tried, it worked.

Then I created a simple web application and then added same dll and tried, it worked.

It is only failing when I am trying through webpart.

I really appreciate if anyone can guide me or give me some tip to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried signing your DLL with the key.snk file provided to you in your SharePoint project? Most of the time, 3rd party libraries need to be rebuilt with the snk file.

You just need to use `ildasm` to convert your dll to an .il file then use the `ilasm` to sign your il file with the snk file and convert it back to .dll

Let me know if you need more details regarding this.